# Resize iframe width according to screen (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, iframe

I writing ASP.NET MVC website.

I display vimeo video player on my webpage

I set it like this.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/197047485?color=ffffff" id="iframe1" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to resize it according to screen.

How I can do this?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Height and width take %.

Comment: Thank's for reply@dbasnett